# Runnig python specifi line from Terminal pycharm and VS and VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

my question is about running specific pythpon code from teminal ,

thats my code:

```
def printName(name)
   print(name)
```

in pycharm  i am choosing this code line with them mouse and click ALT+Shift+E and write in the terminal :

```
>>>name = "amir" 
>>>printName(name) 
>>>amir
```

how could i make the same in VS and VScode?

[Example Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao7x0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please select the code you want to run in VS Code, then right-click (shortcut key is `Shift`+`Enter`), and click "`Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal`", it will enter the python interactive window::

[image]

Then in this interactive window we can enter the python code:

[image]